# Library Won't Update

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, update, library

I'm trying to update my libarchive library on CentOS 7.  Currently, I have version 3.1.2.  If I type the following command, here is the result:

```
# rpm -q libarchive
libarchive-3.1.2-10.el7_2.x86_64
```

I was able to find an .rpm file, online, which provides libarchive 3.5.2.  I'd like to update to this newer version.  So, I attempted to install the package by typing the following:

```
# rpm -i libarchive-3.5.2-1.el9.src.rpm
warning: user mockbuild does not exist -- using root
warning: group mock does not exist -- using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist -- using root
warning: group mock does not exist -- using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist -- using root
warning: group mock does not exist -- using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist -- using root
warning: group mock does not exist -- using root
```

Even though it shows warnings, I would expect that it installed.  After all, they're warnings, not errors.  However, if I type the following command, it doesn't show that the package was installed.

```
# rpm -lq libarchive
/usr/lib64/libarchive.so.13
/usr/lib64/libarchive.so.13.1.2
/usr/share/doc/libarchive-3.1.2
/usr/share/doc/libarchive-3.1.2/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/libarchive-3.1.2/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/libarchive-3.1.2/README
/usr/share/man/man5/cpio.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/mtree.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/tar.5.gz
```

I've also tried compiling from source, based on a downloaded .tar file from the libarchive.org website.  The procedure seems to go well, but I still only show the old, 3.1.2 version of libarchive when typing the `rpm -lq libarchive` command, or the `rpm -q libarchive` command.

So, how would I update this library?  If it has been updated, why don't these commands show that it has been updated?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I've decided to take the advice that both of you have given.  I've decided not to update the library.

I was trying to update the library so that I could install another piece of software -- OpenCoarrays.

Fortunately, I was able to install OpenCoarrays by use of an installation script, which was provided to me.  The script worked, and the program has been installed.  For this reason, I no longer need to update this library.

Thank you for taking the time to provide your input.  You've both been very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The RPM you are trying to install is a SRPM (hence the `.src` in its filename) - it contains the *sources* for the package you want to upgrade.

You need to compile it first for your target system. Use [mock](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/) to do that.

Take great care of not breaking other things if you introduce a newer version of a system lib provided by CentOS. Consider upgrading to EL8 (e.g. Rocky Linux, Alma Linux, or CentOS 8 Stream), you likely save yourself from headaches.

Answer (score 0):

el9 tag in the version you found indicates RHEL 9. As of now in first quarter 2022, still early in its lifecycle, so that came from CentOS Stream 9 or RHEL 9 beta. If you use those operating systems this will be pre-installed. Or of course Fedora is far ahead in versions.

Generic build and install instructions do not use the rpm package manger. To keep the package management experience you expect, take source RPMs intended for RHEL (or Fedora) and rebuild them with the mock tool.

Even when you manage to build an rpm package, there is the question of making it coexist. Important system packages depend on libarchive. And replacing a package from baseos is not something to do lightly. Definitely test this on a not important system first.